# lsof command not found in VS Code terminal

Tags: bash, lsof, npm, visual-studio-code

I am trying to start up my application with `npm start`, however I get the following errors:

`rm: cannot remove 'dist/': Device or resource busy`

When I try to run an `lsof` I get the error message: `bash: lsof: command not found`. I noticed that there is no `/usr/sbin/` inside there, but only `/usr/share` and `/usr/ssl/`.

I am using this Visual Studio Code bash terminal from within a Windows 10 environment.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsb_release -a` to your question? That will help us determine the correct command to use to install lsof.

Comment: Does the `dist` directory lie under one of the windows filesystems such as `/mnt/c` or `/mnt/d`? A frequent cause of "device busy" errors in WSL is when the directory or file is in use by a native Windows program.

Comment: Check this thread: [[WSL] Unable to launch /usr/bin/gdb when setting bash.exe as the integrated shell in VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2811) Especially the json part may resolve your issue I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question I believe you are using WSL on Windows 10, to install lsof you need to run the following command `npm install lsof` since you have npm installed on your machine, or use the traditional way to install it `sudo apt install lsof` from Ubuntu\Debian terminal. regarding the other part, once you install lsof you can use `lsof -D /mypath` then kill the process that use any file in that directory.

Note: if you are using suse then you can use the following commands

```
 sudo zypper ref
 sudo zypper up
 sudo zypper install lsof
```

edit the command above also work in stand alone Ubuntu\Debian or Suse

Comment: I ran an `npm install lsof` and it was successful but bash is still complaining no command found.

Comment: please provide the output of `whereis lsof`

Answer (score 0):

Normally in CentOS/Fedora/RHEL I install it this way:

```
yum install lsof
dnf install lsof
```

Then I can use it. So first try to install it.

Comment: I added additional info to the question.

Comment: I do not use the Windows this way. I am Linux sysadmin. I have no idea. is it a WSL? If yes, then read this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-wsl

Comment: thank you for your help.

Comment: you certainly only run one of these two lines, right? they do the same; `dnf` is the modern "drop-in replacement" for `yum`.

Comment: Yes Marcus Müller, you are right. On Debian family we use apt or apt-get.